# How do you grab the Text widget data from Tkinter in order to freely use the data?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

I am trying to make use of the input text data that is entered through Tkinter's Text widget, the same way one would be able to use the data, it if the data was entered using the `input()` method in python.

Here is my sample code:

```
root=Tk()
root.geometry("750x250")


def retrieve_input():
    input_value = textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    print(input_value)


textBox = Text(root, height=7, width=50)
textBox.pack()
buttonCommit = Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Commit",
                      command=lambda: retrieve_input())

buttonCommit.pack()

mainloop()
```

My issue is that I can see the values printed on the terminal, when I enter something and click the button, but I am not be able to, for instance, loop over the `retrieve_input()` function. Doing a `return input_value` doesn't really result in any output when I loop over the function, using a for loop.

In Short I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
    #.....
    def retrieve_input():
        input_value = textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
        print(input_value)
        return input_value
    
    for a in retrive_input():
       print(a)
   #.....
```

This is Just an example. It could be anything that allows me to use the content data that I enter through Tkinter.

I read somewhere that you somehow need an event handler to run at the appropriate time and capture the data but no idea how that's supposed to be implemented since no sample code was provided.

Comment: `return input_value` should not be generating an exception - please add the traceback message.  On the other hand, it wouldn't actually accomplish anything in your first example, since in the one place you're calling the function, you don't do anything with the return value.  Whatever you do, it has to be in (or called by) some event handler; any top-level code in your program gets executed during startup, before there's any possibility of the user having typed anything into the Text widget.

Comment: _"Doing a return input_value within the function, raises an exception."_ - what is the exception?

Comment: Sorry about that, I was getting an exception from something else. Returning the input just doesn't really doesn't do anything. The for-loop doesn't seem to trigger at all

Comment: Yes, I meant `retrieve_input`,  I will fix that, thanks

Comment: You don't fetch a value like that in a loop.  It's pointless.  Nothing at all can happen in your GUI until tkinter gets back to its main loop to process messages, and it can't do that as long as you are hogging the CPU.  A GUI does all its work by responding to EVENTS.  The event handlers grab the information they need, and return.

Comment: @jasonharper Yes. Thanks for letting me know. But that is exactly where my issue is. I haven't seen any sample code where an event handler is used. Can you please provide me with a sample if you know of any, or edit my code in order for it to contain said event handler?

Comment: @TimRoberts Would you mind providing me with a sample code where an event handler is used? or maybe a source. I am quite new to Tkinter and some of the thinks when it comes to how the GUI works really aren't clear to me

Comment: Your `retrieve_input` is an event handler.  It gets called by tk when your button is clicked, because of the `command` parameter.  That's where you can fetch the text box value and do something with it.  If there haven't been any events, then there's nothing new for you to fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is a) make sure that `retrieve_input` returns the data, and b) make sure that the code that iterates over it doesn't run until the user has a chance to enter some data.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.geometry("750x250")


def retrieve_input():
    input_value = textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    return input_value


def process_input():
    for a in retrieve_input():
        print(a)

textBox = Text(root, height=7, width=50)
textBox.pack()
buttonCommit = Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Commit",
                      command=process_input)
buttonCommit.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Damn Genius! This worked, Many thanks!